# Fetching Data from mongodb in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, jenssegers-mongodb

I have Documents in my mongoDB collection. I need to fetch the count of data associated to the perticular user according to the date. Date is in `MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime Object`. For ex. I need this week's data

Im using `jenssegers/mongodb` packages for this, an tried using `DB:: methods` but failed. Tried with carbon too..

Here is the format stored in mongodb collection

```
{
    "_id": "02ce6ec6-50b1-4c3d-b961-32a3f452c9da",
    "rid": "WW3EvLk9TdwXwfK6AYTyEx5t4PfDWx9xfP",
    "msg": "Hello",
    "ts": {
        "$date": {
            "$numberLong": "1558085847819"
        }
    },
    "u": {
        "_id": "YTyEx5t4PfDWx9xfP",
        "username": "9738084090",
        "name": "Suhas"
    },
    "_updatedAt": {
        "$date": {
            "$numberLong": "1558085847832"
        }
    },
    "mentions": [],
    "channels": []
}
```

Simple like there are multiple entry for ex `YTyEx5t4PfDWx9xfP`, I need to get the total number of entries for that id for the given date.

As of now I'm fetching the data and in loop im counting it
This is what I've tried

```
$weekStart = strtotime(Carbon::now()->startOfWeek()->format('d-m-Y'));
$weekEnd = time();
$videos = DB::connection('mongodb')->collection('collection_name')->>where('file.type','like','video%')->get();
$weekCounts['video'] = 0;
foreach ($videos as $video)
        {
            if ((string)$video['ts']/1000 >= $weekStart &&(string)$video['ts']/1000 <= $weekEnd)
            {
                $weekCounts['video']++;
            }
        }
return $weekCounts;
```

Comment: Can you provide code from your controller?

Comment: Added the Controller Code